# Calculate the surface area bounded by the curves $3x^2−1$ and its tangents that pass through point (0,1/4).

Tags: calculus, functions, area, curves, tangent-line

Ok here i have a calculus problem to solve to find the area of the curve:

Calculate the surface area bounded by the curves $ 3x^2-1 $ and its tangents that pass through point $(0,1/4)$.

My question is how to find the equation of tangents

Comment: The question in the title and body doesn't match. Please edit your question and show your attempts.

Comment: Title says *line* where body says *point*, and title has a negative sign that body does not

Comment: This problem similar to this ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfdGU6F9I6E

Comment: i get complex solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no tangents to the curve $y=3x^2-1$ passing through the point $A=\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right)$

Any line passing through $A$ has equation $y=mx+1/4$ intersects the curve in two distinct points

Substitute in the curve equation $3x^2-1=mx+1/4$ and solve

$$x = \frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2+15}}{6}$$
As $m^2+15>0$ for any $m$ the equation has always two real solutions.